# Why grouping method sum in slick returns Option even if column used for sum is mandatory column?

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

```
CREATE TABLE orders
(
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    ...
    created_on date NOT NULL,
    quantity int NOT NULL,
    ...
    CONSTRAINT orders_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

```
SELECT DATE(o.created_on) AS date, sum(quantity)
FROM orders o
GROUP BY date
```

```
ordersItemsQuery.groupBy(_.createdOn).map{
   case (created, group) => (created, group.map(_.quantity).sum)
}
```

notice quantity is not null column, group.map(_.quantity).sum returns Rep[Option[Int]] but not Rep[Int] why?

Comment: Please tell more about what exactly you want to achieve. This page might help https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question

Comment: Because I don't see the code, I just can guess that `group` type is `Rep[List[DTO]]` where DTO is you case class or type representing part of query, hence `group.map(_.quantity)` is `Rep[List[Int]]`, which implies that `List` can be empty in theory, because the type says it, hence the `sum` of `Nil` is `None`, that's why sum return type is `Option`. If you still would like to get result as Int, you can try use `getOrElse(defaultSumValue)` construction, but I don't this is good way to go, and better to stick with `Option`.

Comment: I understand technically List can be empty. If we group list of tuple and then perform aggregate operation sum as shown below we will not get any Option[T].   `ex:val list: List[(created: DateTime, quantity: Int)] = List((DateTime(1578396037000), 4), (DateTime(1578396037000), 6))` `val groupedQuantity: List[(created: DateTime, quantity: Int)]  = list.groupBy(_._1).map{ case (date, group) => (date, group.map(_._2).sum)}` will return List[(created: DateTime, quantity: Int)] but not List[(created: DateTime, quantity: Option[Int])]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Slick method `sum` evaluates `Option[T]`, and shouldn't be confused with the standard Scala collections method `sum` that returns a non-optional value.

Slick's `sum` is optional because a query may produce no results. That is, if you run `SELECT SUM(column) FROM table` and there are no rows, you do not get back zero from the database. Instead, you get back no rows. Slick is being consistent with this behaviour. Or rather: the `sum` is happening in SQL, on the database server, and doesn't produce a result when there are no rows.

In contrast to the way a database works, Scala's `sum` does allow you to sum an empty list (`List[Int]().sum`) and get back zero.